# Pagination GWT DataGrid for Large Data

Tags: gwt, datagrid, pagination

I have a case where my `DataGrid` might contain thousands of rows of data. My page size is only 50. So I want to get only so much data onto the client from server and load rows of data as and when required. Is there a default support from GWT to do that?

I tried using `PageSizePager` but then realized that the data is already sent to the client and that defeats what am trying to achieve.

Thanks.

Comment: By  using PagingLoadResult gxt we can achieve this

Comment: Is this a feature available in GXT? I don't think GWT has it. Correct?

Comment: It is nothing but remote pagination.If u have bulk records,on page click it will load from proxy.it is an inbuilt feature we must reuse it'

Comment: `AsyncDataProvider` and a `SimplePager`should do the job (in GWT)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate Umit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed. The aim (among others) of `DataGrid`, as well as of any other cell widget, is to display large data sets as fast as possible by using pagination and cells.

I suggest you to start with the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#celltable) about `CellTable` (same applies to `DataGrid`), and [pagination/data retrieval](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#Selection_Data_Paging).

You'll probably need an `AsyncDataProvider` to asynchronously fetch data and an `AbstractPager` (say, `SimplePager`) to force retrieval of more data.
You can also decide to extend the current range of rows (say, infinite scroll), instead having multiple pages (by using `KeyboardPagingPolicy.INCREASE_RANGE`).

In general, the question is too general and can be hardly answered in few lines (or without specify more). The bits are all in the links above, and don't forget to have a look at the cell widgets samples in the [showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList), as they cover almost everything you will need.

Hope to get you started.